# Google colab cannot add comment

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Usually I can make comment with `#` or `"""` for multiline comments. But in the following cases,

```
if i > 0:
                if (df.loc[i, 'data'] <= level1) and \ # Comment
                    (df.loc[i - 1, 'data'] > level1) and \ # Comment
                    not ideal_state:

                    ideal_state_time = df.loc[i,'data']
                    ideal_state = True
```

I got the error

```
  File "<ipython-input-24-07959bc4f436>", line 121
    if (df.loc[i, 'data'] <= level1) and \ # Comment
                                                                                                              ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

What is going on? What's wrong with commenting after the slash? I put the slash there because otherwise it will return an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try replacing `\` (back-slashes) with `()`(brackets) as shown below

```
if( (df.loc[i, 'data'] <= level1) and  # Comment
    (df.loc[i - 1, 'data'] > level1) and  # Comment
    not ideal_state
):
    ideal_state_time = df.loc[i,'data']
    ideal_state = True
```

You can see in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), it's recommended to use brackets

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation.
>
> Backslashes may still be appropriate at times. For example, long, multiple with-statements cannot use implicit continuation, so backslashes are acceptable:
>
> ````
> with open('/path/to/some/file/you/want/to/read') as file_1, \
>      open('/path/to/some/file/being/written', 'w') as file_2:
>     file_2.write(file_1.read())```
> ````

Answer (score 0):

The backslash allows your if to span multiple lines, as it says something like "ignore the upcoming char (newline)"

your interpreter reads it like this:

```
if (df.loc[i, 'data'] <= level1) and # Comment (df.loc[i - 1, 'data'] > lev...
```

And then your interpreter is right, your comment sign does not belong there.

Line continuations may never carry comments.
You're allowed to comment again after `not ideal_state:`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I know if there's a way I can comment after the line so as to allow easy reference when I review my code?

Comment: Following paragraph 2.1.5 of the documentation of python, you may not comment there at all: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html

The only way is to restructure your code like @ardia did.
But even that's kind of ugly imho :/

Answer (score 0):

the backslash "\" is the line continuation character. i.e

```
print "massive super long string that doesn't fit" + \
  "on a single line"
```

only newline charecters/whitespace are allowed after it.